# SQL query not working in Access

Tags: ms-access

My first time using Access

The below query works in SQL Server but when I bring it into access I get the below error message.

```
DECLARE @CandidateNumber INT 
SET @CandidateNumber = 5921368 
UPDATE XXX
SET @CandidateNumber = CandidateNumber = @CandidateNumber + 1 
GO
```

**Error message**: invalid sql statement expected 'delete' 'Insert','Select','Update'

Comment: Access doesn't use variables like this so this definitely will not work. What is this statement doing? Perhaps we can help rewrite this in a way that will work in Access.

Comment: Hi @JNevill thank you for your help. I want to add a column to a table with x rows. The first number in this column should be 5921368 and the last number should be 5921368 + x please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a table linked from SQL-Server, you can use a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) in Access. This type of query is not exectued by the Access engine (JetEngine) but is sent directly to  SQL-Server which executes it.

---

If you are deling with a true Access query, then use a parameter.
See: [Passing parameter to query for Access database](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/256917/Passing-parameter-to-query-for-Access-database)

Comment: It is not, unfortunately. The table is contained within Access.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because Access uses a different dialect of SQL than SQL Server. In particular Access SQL (JET) does not support `DECLARE`-ing variables.

Unfortunately, JET SQL is not well-documented by Microsoft, but there are third-party resources available (for example, a [JET Database Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JET_Database)).

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi. I was not aware they were different.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you need is a query with a *row counter*.

You can use this function and just add the CandidateNumber value:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

See in-line comments for typical usage.